# Contact form/php/hosting errors

Tags: php, contacts, plesk, dreamhost

http://urbanpioneersmusic.com/formpage.html

I'm trying to add a basic contact form I got from bootstrapious to my site but when you click send there is some sort of error happening because it never sends. Here is some backstory:
I used to use godaddy's plesk hosting but switched to dreamhost about a year ago, I contacted dreamhost support and they said these are some of the errors they are getting
[Thu Aug 02 10:05:00 2018] [warn] [client 71.236.128.206] mod_fcgid:
stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/home/dh_v3jvi3/urbanpioneersmusic.com/handler.php) is not within
the allowed path(s): (G:\PleskVhosts\urbanpioneersmusic.com\httpdocs)
in Unknown on line 0, referer:
http://urbanpioneersmusic.com/formpage.html
[Thu Aug 02 10:05:00 2018] [warn] [client 71.236.128.206] mod_fcgid:
stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Operation not
permitted in Unknown on line 0, referer:
http://urbanpioneersmusic.com/formpage.html
[Thu Aug 02 10:08:50 2018] [warn] [client 71.236.128.206] mod_fcgid:
stderr: PHP Warning:  Unknown: open_basedir restriction in effect.
File(/home/dh_v3jvi3/urbanpioneersmusic.com/contact.php) is not within
the allowed path(s): (G:\PleskVhosts\urbanpioneersmusic.com\httpdocs)
in Unknown on line 0
Basically my form is trying to find 
G:\PleskVhosts\urbanpioneersmusic.com\httpdocs
which isn't there. They said to find that in my code and update it. I cannot find pleckvhosts or httpdocs in any of my code. Besides that, I downloaded this form directly from bootstrapious and uploaded it without making any changes except for the sendto email address. I have also built a few brand new sites from scratch that never had anything to do with plesk and they are doing the same thing. Has anyone ever come across something like this? Any advice is greatly appreciated, this is so frustrating.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow - please read [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) and then rewrite your post a little, and _format any code_ according to [how code formatting works here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Right now you've written an impenetrable wall of text. That's not a great way to get real people who take time out of their day to help out on SO, to help you.

Comment: `G:\PleskVhosts\` would  indicate you carried some Windows php.ini settings along. As this is a server setup issue, why didn't the hoster support advise on where to change it?